# How to change class from div parent?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, parent

How do I add a class to .bio by clicking on `.polaroid`?

```js
$(".polaroid").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  if ($(".photogroup").getElementsByClassName("polaroid")[0].hasClass("selected")) {
    $(".photogroup").getElementsByClassName("bio")[0].addClass("showbio");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photogroup">
  <div class="polaroid">
    <div class="foto">
      <img src="images/il-futuro-dei-deboli-che-hanno-coraggioil-rapper-tedua-arriva-a-stezzano_d067474c-23ae-11e8-a2da-ce72c2bcf803_936_1134_big_gallery_linked_i.jpg">
    </div>
    <h3>03/03/2033</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="bio">
    <h3>Evento</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried a few things but none of them work, I also tried going from `.parent()` and `.getElementsByClassName` but it says that `getElementsByClassName` is not a function, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName()` is a vanilla JavaScript function but you are using as if it is jQuery function. You can try using `hasClass()` like the following way:

```js
$(".polaroid").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  if($(".photogroup .polaroid").hasClass("selected")){
      $(".photogroup .bio").addClass("showbio");
  }
});
```

```css
.showbio{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photogroup">
  <div class="polaroid">
      <div class="foto">
          <img src="images/il-futuro-dei-deboli-che-hanno-coraggioil-rapper-tedua-arriva-a-stezzano_d067474c-23ae-11e8-a2da-ce72c2bcf803_936_1134_big_gallery_linked_i.jpg">
      </div>
      <h3>03/03/2033</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="bio">
      <h3>Evento</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have multiple classes with .bio and need to add it only to the one i click onto? Then it needs also to be removed but I can just clear everything and it's easier

Answer (score 0):

well ... it's probably a duplicate but I will answer anyway

First of all - if you're using jQuery you select with $('.class or #id') and then just addClass - also from jQuery, so stick to jQuery

The code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".polaroid").click(function(){
    $(".bio").addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

getElementsByClassName is pure javascript - if you're already using jQuery there is no point in using that. Also because you're completely mixing those jQuery and pure Javasscript in a way that is not going to work. I mean - this line below is gibberish

```
$(".photogroup").getElementsByClassName("bio")[0].addClass("showbio");
```

Proper way of selecting class in pure javascript is explained in details here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: I have multiple .photogroup classes, and need to add .showbio only on the one I click onto, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: In reply to our question I posted another answer - just to make nice formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple .photogroup  classes use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".polaroid").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".bio").addClass("selected");
  });
});
```